# LAN port tester

Tags: ethernet

Is there any way to make a simple LAN port tester that can plug into an ethernet port and check for connectivity.  I dont want to use the cable testers as it require both ends of a cable to be plugged in.  I just want to test signal to a port.

Comment: Connectivity at what [layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)?

Comment: Any computer with an ethernet port will do. If you want it small, some netbooks have RJ-45 ports. Nothing "simple to make" (at reasonable cost for a hobbyist) will test connectivity, but a laptop that's so outdated folks will give it away or throw it out will. If you wanted to throw money at it a smartphone-ish platform would do as well, but none come to mind as having wired ethernet ports standard. If you want to consider what it might cost as test equipment, check the price of the stuff Fluke makes for the job, then pick your jaw up off the floor.

Comment: network layer. i just want to have maybe a small kit that have something with a green light that lights up if there is a signal.

Comment: Install Wireshark.exe. It is a packet sniffer program that works great, though it is made for servers more than client PCs. Do NOT use Wireshark if online with a bank or government agency. They can detect packet sniffers and may block you out.

Comment: @Sparky256 that last part is BS. Unless you mean: if your computer belongs to a bank or government agency.

Comment: @immibis. I mean from a home PC or any PC. I myself have had a PC banned from logging onto a bank because of Wireshark. It puts the Ethernet chip in promiscuous mode so it can see packet headers. They can read your MAC address and block that PC from logging on anymore. If you think it is BS, try it yourself.

Comment: @Sparky256 Your Ethernet chip can always see packet headers, otherwise how would it know where the packets should go? And websites cannot read your MAC address while running wireshark. I've also accessed my own bank's website while running Wireshark. If your bank somehow does do that, you should switch banks because they are hacking your computer.

Comment: @immibis. Maybe the term is 'hacking', but the bank security officer I spoke with said they have the right to block 'suspicious' activity, and they do it by using government issued certificates to read the MAC address of the PC. I had to use another PC to log on again. 'Promiscuous mode' means the user can see the packet headers to all local traffic.

Comment: @Sparky256 They are accessing information on your PC that is not normally meant to be accessible to them; that's "hacking" by my standards. (Their protection is useless anyway. You can bypass it by using a second computer as a router, and running Wireshark on *that* computer)

Comment: Government certs to read mac address, o.m.g. take your tin foil hat some where else.

Comment: @immibis or any switch/router with a monitor port or a hub or wifi. :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple tester is nothing more than a Loopback jack. You tie the tx pairs to the rx pairs of a rj45 Ethernet jack and plug it into the network adapter. The link light should turn on, as well as the activity light. This is enough for the network equipment to negotiate a speed and connection, but would not be useful for data.

Pictured is one for gigabit. 10/100 only need half of this.

[image]

Personally, I've used this to turn on the leds of my android tv box, that only turn on with the Ethernet connection.

Comment: may i know, on what devices can we test this loopback.. because when i try on my pc, it works well. However, when i try it at the LAN port of an oscilloscope, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Does the oscilloscope use Ethernet or is it using a rj45 for a different connection?  This works on 10/100/1000 Ethernet